# Почему не работает сигнал post_save

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Пытаюсь воспроизвести сигнал post_save из туториала

signals.py

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from .models import Product
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(post_save, sender=Product)
def change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print('Signal works!')
```

app.py

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app'
    verbose_name = 'Мое приложение'

    def ready(self):
        import my_app.signals
```

При сохранении любого экземпляра модели `Product`, ничего не происходит. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вроде, всё правильно. Может, Вы не там ищете вывод функции `print`? Попробуйте в сигнале сделать что-то с экземпляром.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Product может быть абстрактной моделью в этой конструкции?

Comment: Не уверен, но кажется, что именно из-за абстрактной модели это не работает. При беглом поиске натолкнулся на следующее решение: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17173716/11558617.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Спасибо, но кажется у меня кроме этого проблема посерьезнее. Если написать сигнал для модели, унаследованной от абстрактной и вызвать `save` в django shell, то все срабатывает. А если вызывается мой метод, в котором явно прописан shell, то это почему-то не работает :(

Comment: _"метод, в котором явно прописан shell"_. Может, Вы имели в виду `save`? Кстати, Вы пробовали банально перезагружать сервер? Если через `shell` работает, то и в коде должно.

Comment: Да, опечатался. `save`, конечно. Сервер тестовый джанговый, он перезагружается при каждом изменении. Я даже ставил точку останова где написано `model.save()`. Сохранение происходит, а сигнал не срабатывает. Ничего не понимаю.

Comment: Перезагрузите, пожалуйста, сервер. Это важно!

Comment: @nomnoms12 Да я перезагружал) Не работает, буду ковыряться дальше

Comment: @nomnoms12 все, дошло) Я просто запутался в своих классах) За решение с абстрактным классом - спасибо. Попробую седлать как там написано.